# Warning for overflow in std::accumulate

Tags: c++, warnings, clang-tidy

Is there any way to get a warning for std::accumulate when the type of the `init` arg doesn't match the contained type you are accumulating over? e.g. in this example we shouldn't accumulate a 32 bit value when iterating over a vector of 64 bit ints. But it's pretty easy to just pass in 0 and forget to pass 0LL. Is there any way to get a warning for this? `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion` doesn't seem to help. I also tried looking for clang tidy checks that may work, but didn't find anything there either.

```
std::vector<long long> a = {10000000000, 10000000000};
cout << std::accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 0) << "\n"; // overflows
cout << std::accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 0LL) << "\n"; // prints 20000000000
```

Answer (score 8):

Oh, I found the right clang-tidy check:
[`misc-fold-init-type`](https://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clang-tidy/checks/misc-fold-init-type.html)